# how can I find a matching pattern between two words using sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I want to search a pattern in paragraph that begins with word1 and end with word2 and print the first line of the paragraph if the pattern match, I am not sure if I can do it using grep 
for example if I have the following file and I am looking for aaa

```
Word1 this is paragraph number 1 
aaa
bbb
ccc
word2

Word1 this is paragraph number 2 
bbb
ccc
ddd
word2
```

the answer should be like that

```
Word1 this is paragraph number 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this `awk`:

```
awk '/^Word1/{f=1;l="";hold=$0} /word2$/{f=0; if(l ~ /aaa/){print hold}} f{l = l RS $0}' file
```

Comment: Not for all cases, because the `word2` is assumed in every paragraph. For example, add two additional paragraphs, one that begins with `word1` and ends with `word4` and another that begins with `word7` and ends with `word2`. If `aaa` is only found in the second one it will print the header of the first one because it tries to match all lines between `word1` and `word2` although they belong to different paragraphs.

Comment: This isn't really even all that close to doing what was requested. Sure it'll produce the posted expected output given the posted sample input but that's just because the posted sample input wasn't very well thought out. Try it when your paragraphs only **contain** word1 and word2 rather than starting with them. Try it when word1 isn't even present at all. Try it when word1 is in 1 paragraph and word2 in a different one.

Comment: Well, at least now it's checking for word1/word at the start/end of a **line** but that's still not checking for it at the start/end of a **paragraph** and it still doesn't check for which paragraph the 2 words are in. The OP seems happy with it though so idk....

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^Word1/!b;:a;N;/^word2/M!ba;/^aaa/MP' file
```

Ignore any lines that do not begin `Word1`. Collect lines in the pattern space until a line beginning `word2` or the end of the file. If a match is made then match also on the required string (in this case `aaa`). If a match is made print the first line and repeat.

EDIT: If paragraphs can end in other words i.e. `word3`, use this:

```
sed -n '/^Word1/!b;:a;N;/^$/Mb;/^word2/M!ba;/^aaa/MP' file
```

Comment: @123 see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command)

Comment: It assumes all paragraphs end with `word2`. If that precondition doesn't occur, the command will match `aaa` in every line between previous `word1` and following `word2`, although they belong to different paragraphs.

Comment: @Birei from the way the question was written I took it as given that paragraphs of interest began with`word1` and ended with `word2`. However see edit for amended solution for you interpretation.

Comment: Yes. Your interpetration seems right, based in the accepted answer, that has similar issue, and works fine for the OP.

Answer (score 3):

This is the simple, idiomatic awk solution:

```
$ awk -v RS= -F'\n' '/^Word1.*aaa.*word2$/{print $1}' file
Word1 this is paragraph number 1
```

If that doesn't do what you want then edit your question to clarify your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one liner AWK:

```
 awk '/Word1/{l=$0;flag=1;next}/word2/{flag=0}flag && $0 ~ /aaa/ && !c{print l; c++}' file
```

Input:

```
Word1 this is paragraph number 1 
aaa
aaa
bbb
aaa
word2

Word1 this is paragraph number 2 
bbb
ccc
ddd
word2
```

Output:

```
Word1 this is paragraph number 1
```

Comment: it's working but I want to get as an output the first line of the paragraph where the pattern has been found

Comment: @malmo I hadn't tried my previous script, it was wrong!! The script syntax was incorrect. It's OK now

Comment: Does your command wait to check if paragraph ends with `word2` before printing the header line? And, how about if there are many lines in each paragraph with `aaa`? It will print the header once for each match.

Comment: @Birei It is true.I was checking Word2 instead of word2. Now if there is more than one pattern only prints one header

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution (that doesn't match exactly what you asked for):

```
awk -F'\n' -v RS= '/bbb/{print $1}' file
```

This skips finding Word1/Word2, and assumes that you have a blank line between records as in your example.

Of course, you could always force the blank line beforehand, with sed:

```
gsed 's/^Word1/\n&/' file | ...above...
```