# How can I print the first line and the pattern of a paragraph using sed or awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I want to search a pattern in paragraph that begins with CREATE NEW and ends with ";" and print the first line of the paragraph and the line that contains the pattern if the pattern match. for example if I have the following file and I am looking for Lines that begin with FROM

```
CREATE NEW paragraph num 1  
FROM file1 
FROM file2 
USING file3 
;
CREATE NEW paragraph num 2 
FROM file2
FROM file6
FROM file5
USING file4
;
```

the result would be like :

```
CREATE NEW paragraph num 1 ;FROM file1 ;FROM file2
CREATE NEW paragraph num 2 ;FROM file2 ;FROM file6 ;FROM file5
```

I managed to print the first line using the answer of the following question [how can I find a matching pattern between two words using sed or awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35335409/how-can-i-find-a-matching-pattern-between-two-words-using-sed-or-awk) but I don't know how to print the lines that contain the pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this awk command:

```
awk 'p!="" && $0==";"{print p} p!="" && /^FROM /{p = p "; " $0} /^CREATE NEW /{p=$0}' file
CREATE NEW paragraph num 1 ; FROM file1 ; FROM file2
CREATE NEW paragraph num 2 ; FROM file2; FROM file6; FROM file5
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
awk '/CREATE NEW/,/;/ {
if($1=="CREATE") 
    printf("\n%s ;",$0);
else if($1=="FROM")
    printf("%s ;",$0);
            }' fileToSearch
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
ed -nr '/CREATE NEW/,/^;/{/^CREATE NEW/h;/^FROM/H;/^;/!d;g;s/\s*\n/ ;/gp}' file
```

This collects line beginning `CREATE NEW` and containing the lines starting `FROM` and replaces the preceeding spaces and newlines with `;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk to match the pattern and print matched pattern and line number
as follows

```
BEGIN{
  line_num = 0;
  print "LineNo : Matched Pattern"
}
{ 
  line = $0
  line_num++;
  if(line ~ /^CREATE NEW / || $NF==";" || line ~/^FROM /)
    print line_num," : " line
}
END
{
}
```